# The getter 'sign_out' isn't defined for the type 'LineIcons'

Tags: android, flutter

[What's the wrong in this code and why i got this error - The getter 'sign_out' isn't defined for the type 'LineIcons'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RGe0.png)

Comment: Did you run flutter pub get ?

Comment: yes, but i got the same error again and again.

Comment: Devendra please be more detailed when asking a question. 
You can checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1):

According to the image linked with this question, what I can say is that 'LineIcons' package has been installed successfully as there is no squiggle line on the bottom where it has been declared!

Possible reason for this error could be,

> You updated the LineIcons package and now they removed "sign_out" or have renamed it.

#### Solution

Update LineIcons in pubspec.yaml to,

```
 line_icons: ^2.0.1
```

and use their latest alt icon for sign-out

```
 Icon(LineIcons.alternateSignOut)
```

Use this [link to LineIcons](https://icons8.com/line-awesome) to search for icons that you need!

NOTE: I would not recommend downgrading this package for the purpose.